System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize - Cosmos
When I try to initialize my Cosmos client in the background worker service, I get the error.
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize 
\---\> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type  'System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.
at System.RuntimeType.ActivatorCache..ctor(RuntimeType)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean) 
at System.Configuration.Internal.ConfigSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem.Init(Type, Object\[\] ) 
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem() 
\--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem() 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem() 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String) 
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings() 
**at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient.Initialize**(Uri, ConnectionPolicy , Nullable`1 , HttpMessageHandler , ISessionContainer , Nullable`1 , IStoreClientFactory , TokenCredential , String , RemoteCertificateValidationCallback , CosmosClientTelemetryOptions ) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri, AuthorizationTokenProvider, EventHandler`1, ConnectionPolicy , Nullable`1 , JsonSerializerSettings , ApiType , EventHandler`1 , HttpMessageHandler , ISessionContainer , Nullable`1 , Func\`2 , IStoreClientFactory , Boolean , String , RemoteCertificateValidationCallback , CosmosClientTelemetryOptions , AvailabilityStrategy , IChaosInterceptorFactory ) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.Create(CosmosClient, CosmosClientOptions) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient..ctor(String, AuthorizationTokenProvider, CosmosClientOptions)

My Code Snippet
var endPoint = "https:/endpoint-URI:443/"; 
var key = "api-Key"; 

CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endPoint,key); // i get error here
var databaseName = "dbName"; 
var containerName = "containerName"; 
var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);  
var upsertOrder = new  
{ 
   id = new Guid(), 
   Partition = "", 
   Ticker = "ABC" 
}; 
var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(item: upsertOrder) 

I should be able to initialize the cosmos client access the data

what SDK version do you use?

i use .Net 8 version

I asked about the version of CosmosDb SDK, but not the version of .NET

i use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos  - 3.43.1

I cannot reproduce the problem with your code. check this because it seems the problem is not related to Cosmos

This error is unrelated to the Cosmos DB SDK. The reason the SDK is the origin of the exception is because it attempts to use the System.Configuration APIs.
The error is related to the app configuration and the framework being used having some issue with the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package.
See:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2049
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46900

